# Node.js hooks execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using expressjs, as described below i can get the response easily. I am using same code for all request. But i want to execute pre and post hooks before and after executing the code below.

```
app.get('/products', function (req, res, next) {
 //get products from the database.
 next();
});
```

Pre and post hooks are declared in different files and they will be loaded dynamically based on some condition. Even, i don't know if a hook is declared or not.I searched on **stackoverflow** and get two solutions: **eval() and new Function()**. These function will take the string and will return function and then that function can be executed. I want to know, is there any other solution in Nodejs to execute dynamically loaded function?

Comment: pre-hooks can be implemented with Express middleware.  I don't really know what you mean by post-hooks.  The response has already been sent at that point and cannot be influenced.

Comment: Please let me know some example for pre hook. Post hook will executed after above code. I want to generalize these hook not only for one command

Comment: Just look up "Express middleware" for pre-hooks.  You can examine every single incoming request and modify it, bypass the other handlers, log it, etc.. I don't know of any post-hooks in Express.